# I accidentally deleted sonarqube administrator in sonar db, users table.. how to create administrator in sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube

I accidentally deleted sonarqube administrator in sonar db, users table.. I can't access sonarqube instance ... how create new adminstrator in sonarqube ... pleace help me.
Thanks

Comment: If possible you could create a new instance with new db and copy the admin user to the current db.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/security/#header-3):

> ### Reinstating Admin Access
>
> If you changed and then lost the admin password, you can reset it using the following query:
>
> ```
> update users set
> crypted_password='100000$t2h8AtNs1AlCHuLobDjHQTn9XppwTIx88UjqUm4s8RsfTuXQHSd/fpFexAnewwPsO6jGFQUv/24DnO55hY6Xew==', 
>   salt='k9x9eN127/3e/hf38iNiKwVfaVk=', 
>   hash_method='PBKDF2', 
>   reset_password='true', 
>   user_local='true' 
> where login='admin';
> ```
>
> If you've deleted admin and subsequently locked out the other users with global administrative permissions, you'll need to re-grant admin to a user with the following query:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO user_roles(uuid, user_uuid, role) 
> VALUES ('random-uuid',
> (select uuid from users where login='mylogin'), 
> 'admin');
> ```